# Can Python's Bunch be used recursively?

Tags: python, bunch

Using [**`bunch`**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bunch/1.0.1), can `Bunch` be used recursively?

For example:

```
from bunch import Bunch
b = Bunch({'hello': {'world': 'foo'}})
b.hello
>>> {'world': 'foo'}
```

So, obviously:

```
b.hello.world
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-effaad77643b> in <module>()
----> 1 b.hello.world

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'world'
```

I know I could do...

```
b = Bunch({'hello': Bunch({'world': 'foo'})})
```

...but that's awful.

Answer (score 4):

Dug into the source code, this can be done with the `fromDict` method.

```
b = Bunch.fromDict({'hello': {'world': 'foo'}})
b.hello.world
>>> 'foo'
```

Answer (score 2):

`Bunch.fromDict` could do this magic for you:

```
>>> d = {'hello': {'world': 'foo'}}
>>> b = Bunch.fromDict(d)
>>> b
Bunch(hello=Bunch(world='foo'))
>>> b.hello
Bunch(world='foo')
>>> b.hello.world
'foo'
```